# Problems with opening .pro files only in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt

We are making software using the qt framework for the team project.

The creator of the initial template created and shared a .pro file in the Windows environment. I'm a Mac user and I opened this .pro file but the header or source file doesn't open and only .pro files open.

Also, I can't build it.
How do I solve it?

.pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: how did you install Qt? it seems you dont have correct compiler to run `qmake` for you.
try using `qmake` in terminal and test that you can compile it without qt-creator or not.

Comment: Are the files mentioned in the pro file located in the same folder as the pro file itself? Are  you able to locate hem in Finder?

Comment: I tied to use qmake in terminal but I got an error "Project ERROR: failed to parse default search paths from compiler output"